# Ant archiving subfolders

Tags: ant, zip, task, archive, target

I have next trouble. I have one folder("FirstFolder") and 3 subfolders("1", "2", "3"). I want to archive this folders in next - 1.acp, 2.acp, 3.acp and placed in other folder. It's important - I do not know what are called sub-folders and their number!!! I don't found solutions for this and write simple ant task-

```
<target name="start">
  <foreach target="zipAcp" param="Files">
    <path>
      <dirset dir="src/main/bootstrap"/>
    </path>
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="zipAcp">
  <zip destfile="target/classes/alfresco/extension/agilent/${Files}.acp" basedir="src/main/bootstrap"/>
</target>
```

But i don't know how get directory name(1), but not full path as now(D:\test\1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [basename](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html) task for getting directory name.

Comment: Wanted to add about ant properties immutability and hint for using  `<var unset="true"/>` inside `for`. But found this had been already refactored in separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001521/ant-immutable-properties-to-mutable :)