# Ant immutable properties to mutable

Tags: java, maven, ant, build

i have a problem. I'm use antrun plugin for maven and do next: i have folder and subfolders(I do not know what are called sub-folders and their number) and i'm do archive for this subfolders with their name(subfolder name - "1", archive name - "1.acp").

```
               <tasks>
                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="${settings.localRepository}/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpath="${settings.localRepository}/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
                  <for param="file">
                      <path>
                          <dirset dir="src/main/bootstrap" includes="/*" />
                      </path>
                      <sequential>
                          <basename property="dir" file="@{file}" />
                          <zip destfile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/alfresco/extension/agilent/${dir}.acp" basedir="@{file}" />
                      </sequential>
                  </for>
              </tasks>
```

But property dir is immutable!!! And all archive has name "1.acp". How to make this property mutable or do this another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a 1.8 Ant's [Local task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html)

In your case:

```
<sequential>
  <local name="dir"/>
  <basename property="dir" file="@{file}"/>
  <zip
    destfile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/alfresco/extension/agilent/${dir}.acp" 
    basedir="${dir}"
  />
</sequential>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [var task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) from ant contrib.

The property `unset`, lets you reset values(example from above link):

```
    <property name="x" value="6"/>
    <echo>${x}</echo>   <!-- will print 6 -->
    <var name="x" unset="true"/>
    <property name="x" value="12"/>
    <echo>${x}</echo>   <!-- will print 12 -->
```

So you will have to fix it to:

```
 <sequential>
   <var name="dir" unset="true"/>
   <basename property="dir" file="@{file}" />
   <zip destfile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/alfresco/extension/agilent/${dir}.acp" basedir="@{file}" />
 </sequential>
```